# Load Thumbnail into Div and use cloud-zoom

Tags: jquery, cloud, zooming

I am having a problem with loading an thumbnail into a div then using cloud zoom on it, basically the html is like this:

```
<!-- The Original Image -->
<p class="product-image product-image-zoom replace">
<a class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" href="src/to/img.jpg" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4">
<img id="" src="src/to/img.jpg" />
</a>
</p>


<div class="more-views">
   <ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""><img class="image-rollover" src="source/to/img.jpg" width="67" height="67"/></a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href=""><img class="image-rollover" src="source/to/img.jpg" width="67" height="67"/></a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href=""><img class="image-rollover" src="source/to/img.jpg" width="67" height="67"/></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery I am using to load each thumbnail into the main img tag:

```
jQuery('.image-rollover').hover(function() {
jQuery('.replace img').attr("src", this.src);
jQuery('.zoom').attr("href", this.src);
});
```

I am also using cloud zoom on the main image:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js') ?>"></script>
```

So Here is my problem: The thumbnails load into the div okay, but every time I hover over the newly loaded thumbnail, the cloud zoom comes up, but still shows the initial image, is there a way I can get the cloud zoom to show the current image that is loaded in?

[a busy cat http://beta2.stocksale.ca/picture.png](http://beta2.stocksale.ca/picture.png)

PLEASE HELP!!! AHHHH!!!

Answer (score 4):

Simply re-call `*$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();*` after the jQuery operations.